# Find all the folders that are concealed using 'chflags'

Tags: bash, grep, find, macos, xattr

I have concealed some folders on my laptop using `chflags`:

```
chflags hidden hide-me
```

And I don't remember where exaclty these folders are located.

How is it possible to find all of them? (Probably by using `find` and/or `grep`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like that:

```bash
find . -flags -hidden \! -name ".DS_Store"
```

Comment: Thanks. Out of curiosity, how you figured out that I asked this for macOS? `chflags` seems to be a part of BSD as well.

Comment: Sorry, I don't find "`chflags`" on my Linux system and is not available. So, a simple "`man chflags`" search on internet show me "`chflags`" and "`macos`" on first response